# "version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found" error running gdal in anaconda env

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, gdal, anaconda3

I've been relocating a geodjango project from Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04, creating a conda env from a yml file, running the server I got this error

```
version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /lib/libgdal.so.26)
```

from other posts I got to check the following:

I ran  strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX and got:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

so the version required IS installed

running locate libstdc++.so.6 i got:

```
/home/fcr/anaconda3/envs/fcr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/fcr/anaconda3/envs/fcr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/home/fcr/anaconda3/envs/fcr/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/fcr/anaconda3/envs/fcr/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/home/fcr/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/fcr/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26
/home/fcr/anaconda3/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-8.2.0-hdf63c60_1/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/fcr/anaconda3/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-8.2.0-hdf63c60_1/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/home/fcr/anaconda3/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-8.2.0-hdf63c60_1/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot      /lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/fcr/anaconda3/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-8.2.0-hdf63c60_1/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot  /lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/home/fcr/anaconda3/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/fcr/anaconda3/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26
/home/fcr/anaconda3/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/fcr/anaconda3/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26
/home/fcr/anaconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6
/home/fcr/anaconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.26
/snap/core/9066/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/core/9066/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
/snap/core/9066/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py
/snap/core18/1705/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/core18/1705/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/snap/core18/1705/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-   gdb.py
/snap/core18/1754/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/core18/1754/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/snap/core18/1754/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
/snap/vlc/1620/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/123/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/123/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/123/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25-gdb.py
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
/usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28-gdb.py
```

is there too many installations of the compiler?, how can I get around this?

thanks

Comment: I am running in to the same issue. has anyone found a solution?

Comment: I manage to solve it by defining in settings.py the location of the library GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/local/lib/libgdal.so'